# Problem using XPath to Parse XML String Data

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm trying to use XPath to parse an XML string but I am getting only null values back. Does anyone have an idea where I might be going wrong in the code shown below?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String content = "<imagesXML><Images><Image><ImageUID Scope='Public' Type='Guid' Value='{7f2535d0-9a41-4997-9694-0a4de569e6d9}'/><CorbisID Scope='Public' Type='String' Value='42-15534232'/><Title Scope='Public' Type='String' Value='Animal'/><CreditLine Scope='Public' Type='String' Value='¬© Robert Llewellyn/Corbis'/><IsRoyaltyFree Scope='Public' Type='Boolean' Value='False'/><AspectRatio Scope='Public' Type='String' Value='1.500000'/><URL128 Scope='Public' Type='String' Value='http://cachens.corbis.com/CorbisImage/thumb/15/53/42/15534232/42-15534232.jpg'/></Image></Images></imagesXML>";
    InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(content));
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList list = null;
    try {
        list = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("//URL128[@Value]", source,
                XPathConstants.NODESET);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.item(i));
    }
}
```

The output from System.out is 'value=[URL128: null]', but it should be the URL I am trying to extract: `http://cachens.corbis.com/CorbisImage/thumb/15/53/42/15534232/42-15534232.jpg`.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if you try changing your XPath evaluation statement from this:

```
list = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("//URL128[@Value]", 
    source, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

to this:

```
list = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("//URL128/@Value", 
    source, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I get Value="http://cachens.corbis.com/CorbisImage/thumb/15/53/42/15534232/42-15534232.jpg"
Is there any way to remove the Value= part using the XPath evaluation?

Comment: ahhh, got it  System.out.println(list.item(i).getTextContent());

Comment: @c12: Sure, you could do that with `String#replace` or `String#replaceAll` if you know that it will not be represent in the body of the String. -- never mind, your way is better!

Answer (score 1):

Note:

- The expression `//URL128[@Value]` returns a list of all `URL123` elements having a `Value` attribute
- The expression `//URL128/@Value` returns a list of the `Value` attributes from each `URL128` element in the source

Neither of these lists contain strings; they contain DOM types. You've got only one `URL128` element in your source, yet you're asking for a `NodeList`. You could simplify by using the following:

```
String url = xPath.evaluate("//URL128/@Value", source);
```